# difference between force_tz and tz <-

Tags: r, lubridate

In R I have a vector of dates

```
dd = ymd_hms("2020-07-04 15:36:50")
tz(dd) #"UTC"
```

To specify the time zone, what is the difference between using `force_tz` or simply setting the `tz`?

```
library(lubridate)
dd = ymd_hms("2020-07-04 15:36:50") 
tz(dd) # UTC

dd1 = dd ; tz(dd1) <- 'Europe/Zurich'
dd1 # "2020-07-04 15:36:50 CEST"

dd2 = dd ; dd2 = force_tz(dd2, 'Europe/Zurich')
dd2 #"2020-07-04 15:36:50 CEST"
```

Comment: Read `help("tz<-")`.

Comment: okay, so it's the same